# My simulation ends at 0s in Castalia?

Tags: omnet++

My simulation ends even before starting. I am trying to figure out the reason but really i have no clue.

Here is what i get in text file.

```
Castalia| what:area (1)
Castalia| when:2017-10-26 18:37
Castalia| label:area
Assigned runID=General-0-20171026-18:37:53-3908
Setting up network `SN'...
Initializing...
Running simulation...
** Event #1   T=0   Elapsed: 0.000s (0m 00s)  0% completed   ev/sec=0
```

Answer (score 0):

I have solved this issue.

The problem was in initialize() function. I was trying to access the transmission level as following:

```
TransmissionLevel = getParentModule()->getSubmodule("communication")->getSubmodule("radio")->par("TxOutputPower");
```

and somehow it doesn't work.